Amazon SES DKIM failure with verified email
We are currently experiencing issues with sending emails via Amazon SES due to DKIM problems. The email identity is verified in SES. According to SES documentation, DKIM should be automatically generated for email identities. However, we are unsure if additional configurations are needed in our DNS settings. The EasyDKIM option for generating DKIM is disabled because we are using an email identity instead of a domain identity.
Do we need to manually add the DKIM provided by SES to our the email we are creating in code? We haven't included anything with DKIM in the code, as we believe this might be a DNS issue. Currently, we are only using the verified email to send emails.
For context, the domain is managed by a third party, which is why we are using an email identity instead of a domain identity. We prefer to continue using a verified email identity.
Additionally, we have already added the SPF record, and while authentication is not failing, other issues persist. (See attached image)
Did anyone have this problem before, and what was the solution for your case. Any help is appreciated!
